# scheme - why does this function take much longer to run

Tags: scheme, racket

I have these two functions, foldl and foldr. After a chain of function definitions were made i tested two alternatives, and the only differences i could find between the two chains for function calls and definitions was between these two functions, and for some reason the function that calls foldr takes exceptionally longer (tested with large input)

Here is foldl:

```
(define (foldl op z ls) 
  (if (null? ls) 
  z 
  (foldl op (op z (car ls)) (cdr ls))))
```

and here is foldr:

```
(define (foldr op z ls)
  (if (null? ls)
  z
  (op (car ls) (foldr op z (cdr ls)))))
```

My question is why does the chain that calls **foldr**, take a ridiculously **longer time** to run compared to the chain that calls **foldl**?

Comment: define "ridiculously" in "ridiculously longer". is it 10% more time? 100% (i.e., twice slower)? is it 10x slower? 100x? What *is* your code? What is your *data*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `foldl` is tail recursive because the `foldl` is the last function called each time through. Your implementation of `foldr` is not tail recursive because `op` is the last thing called each time through.

Ok, so what does that mean?

When `foldl` calls itself each time through, `op` has already been applied and returned a value. The compiler can optimize this into an equivalent loop. In contrast, when `foldr` calls itself, `op` still needs to be applied and so the program must remember to apply `op` after the recursive call to `foldr` returns a value. Unfortunately, the recursive call to `foldr` cannot return a value until `op` is applied to the next recursive call to `foldr` and so on until the end of the list. Then at the end of the list, each of the pending applications of `op` must be applied one by one.

Remembering all the applications of `op` that are pending takes time and memory space.

Comment: Thanks heaps, very well explained. :)